# Why is my plugin version 0.1?

Tags: plugin-development

If you look at the changelog, it says my version number is 1.0.0.

If you look at the button to download, it says 0.1.

Also, if you hover over it (or click it), the url says 1.0.0, and the svn repository also only has the tag 1.0.0.

I'm just wondering how to change the version number on the button, and in the `compatibility` section, and in the developers tab under current version.

Here's the link to the plugin: http://wordpress.org/plugins/leaflet-map/changelog/

Here's the svn tags directory: http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/leaflet-map/tags/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your version number in your plugin header.

leaflet-map.php:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Leaflet Map
Plugin URI: http://twitter.com/bozdoz/
Description: A plugin for creating a Leaflet JS map with a shortcode.
Version: 0.1
Author: Benjamin J DeLong
Author URI: http://twitter.com/bozdoz/
License: GPL2
*/
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  I wasn't sure what the plugin header was.  Too many attributes in too many folders/files.  :)